# Updating three way junction table in SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

**Update**

The problem is that when the object is persited into the database for every change a new **INSERT** expession is generated. What I need is only one **INSERT** which to include all of the columns.

```python
#First **INSERT** request
plane.hangar.appen(hangar)
#Second **INSERT** request
users.planes.append(plane)
```

I have the following database structure described with **SqlAlchemy**. What I want to do is to insert a new record in the table "**`users_planes_hangars`**". I'm trying to do that in the following way:

```python
plane= dbSession.query(Plane).filter(Plane.plane_id == planeId).first()
garage = dbSession.query(Hangar).filter(Hangar.hangar_id == hangarId).first()

plane.hangar.appen(hangar)
users.planes.append(plane)
dbSession.commit()
```

The problem is that the executed query (the query below) does not include the `user_id`, it only  includes the `plane_id` and the `hangar_id`.

```sql
INSERT INTO users_planes_hangars (plane_id, hangar_id) VALUES (%(plane_id)s, %(hangar_id)s) 
RETURNING users_planes_hangars.user_id' {'hangar_id': 4, 'plane_id': 16}
```

```python
|usersTabe| <--- |users_planes_hangars_table| ---> |planesTable|
                              |
                             \|/
                          |hangarsTable|

class User(object):
    pass

class Plane(object):
    pass

class Hangar(object):
    pass    

usersMeta = Table("user",
    Column("user_id", Integer, primary_key = True)
)

mapper(User, usersMeta, properties = {
    "planes": relationship(Plane, usersPlanesHangars)
})


planesMeta = Table("planes",
    Column("plane_id", Integer, primary_key = True)
)
mapper(Plane, planesMeta, properties = {
    "hangar": relationship(Hangar, usersPlanesHangars)
})


hangarMeta = Table("hangars",
    Column("hangar_id", Integer, primary_key = True)
)


usersPlanesHangars = Table("users_planes_hangars",
    Column("user_id", Integer, ForeinKey("users.user_id"), primary_key = True)
    Column("plane_id", Integer, ForeinKey("planes.plane_id"), primary_key = True)
    Column("hangar_id", Integer, ForeinKey("hangar.hangar_id"), primary_key = True)
)
```

Comment: How do 'Car' and 'Garage' come into picture?

Answer (score 0):

you need to map usersPlanesHangars to a class, and explicitly create an instance of UsersPlanesHangars each time you'd like one of these rows to be inserted.

My guess here is that the m2m is really between planes and users, and the hangar is associated with each plane/user association.  You'd likely consider a pattern like [Association Object](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/relationships.html#association-object) for this.